# How does the Android OS notify of any event?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm a beginner in Android development and have recently got introduced to idea of Android`BroadcastReceiver`.

If I understand it correctly, `BroadcastReceiver` is something with which we register a class to listen for an event like the arrival of a new SMS or detection of a new Bluetooth device etc.

What I want to know is, how the Android OS itself detects the happening of an event and how it, in turn, notifies (broadcasts) all the classes about the event.

Does it run some kind of `Service` at the back in order to be notified of an event?

Comment: android os doesn't depend on java only. It also has linux commands running with the OS. So I think it is somewhat done with them

Comment: That's what I want to know, the internal process